# Labeling factors (encoding for ML)

Tags: r, data-science

There is a method of labeling categorical variables:
for e.g.

```
listings$require_guest_phone_verification <- factor(listings$require_guest_phone_verification,
                                               levels = c('f', 't'),
                                               labels = c(0, 1))
```

This is require_guest_phone_verification column which I encoded as an example. Similar to this there is a name field, in which there are numerous types names, which cannot be defined statistically. These must be some dynamic way to do that.

We need to follow dynamic way for both levels and labels. It does sounds simple but always ended up have some error. I have already used this for levels below:

```
 levels = c(paste(shQuote(levels(listings$name)), collapse=", "))
```

Do suggest if someone has better approach for levels and labels.

Attaching name column screenshot here (showing end entries only):

[image]

Comment: You should provide example data and expected outputs. Have a look at the dummies package for encoding data. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dummies/dummies.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Seems helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of data in name column and due to number encoding it is almost impossible. we can do that by having dummy variables though.

```
 dummy.data.frame(listings, names=c("name"), sep=",")
```